# How to display props or state in alert?

Tags: reactjs

How to display props or state in alert box ?
how to display it on alert box as we print on console.

```
 alert('Props',this.props);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSON.stringify to convert it to string.

alert('props: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props));

Answer (score 3):

Alert takes only one parameter. If you want to do something like that you should write:

`alert('props' + this.props);`